# append a list element-wise to elements of a nested list in R

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I'm new to R and still trying to get my head around the apply family instead of using loops.

I have two lists, one nested, the other not, both composed of characters:

```
>lst1 <- list(c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), c("JKL", "MNO", "PQR"))
>lst2 <- c("abc", "def")
```

I would like to create a third list such that each element of lst2 is appended as the last element of the respective sublist in lst1. The desired output looks like this:

```
>lst3
[[1]]
[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "abc"

[[2]]
[1] "JKL" "MNO" "PQR" "def"
```

My experience thus far in R tells me there likely is a way of doing this without writing a loop explicitly.

Comment: I'd do `mapply(c, lst1, lst2, SIMPLIFY=F)`, but this is probably not what you are looking for ("no loop")?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Map` which does exactly what `mapply(..., simplify = F)` do:

```
Map(c, lst1, lst2)
[[1]]
[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "abc"

[[2]]
[1] "JKL" "MNO" "PQR" "def"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use `lapply` if you apply your function over the length of your `lst1` vector. This works:

```
lapply(1:length(lst1),function(i) append(lst1[[i]],lst2[[i]]))

[[1]]
[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "abc"

[[2]]
[1] "JKL" "MNO" "PQR" "def"
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` will not do what you need. You can use a loop with `append` to do this:

```
list1 <- list(c("ABC","DEF","GHI"),c("JKL","MNO","PQR"))
list2 <- c("abc","def")

listcomplete <- list(c("ABC","DEF","GHI","abc"),c("JKL","MNO","PQR","def"))

for (i in 1:length(list2)) {
  list1[[i]] <- append(list1[[i]],list2[i])
}
```

Results:

```
> list1
[[1]]
[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "abc"

[[2]]
[1] "JKL" "MNO" "PQR" "def"
```